# Getting file path from polymer to Java program

Tags: java, polymer

I have a Java program that takes around 1000 files as input and performs some necessary functions on it and return new files as output. This works fine. I have made the UI for this using Polymer.js and the issue I am facing is of file path. My Java program receives fake path from the Polymer UI and therefore I am unable to process my files. 
Any solution by which I can provide my files to Polymer and receive exact file paths in Java program and perform necessary functions on it.

Thanks